# Nuget Packager Error - Access is denied

Tags: nuget, tfs-2015

Using TFS 2015.3 I am trying to create nuget packages to share internally  with TFS out-of-the-box Nuget Packager Task. However, it does not create packages and errors out complaining "Access is denied". Inline are its log

```
2017-04-12T20:46:59.3533843Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\Downloads\TFS Agent installer\agent\tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.58
2017-04-12T20:46:59.3846316Z Executing the powershell script: C:\Downloads\TFS Agent installer\agent\tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.58\NuGetPackager.ps1
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6033861Z Getting version number from build
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6033861Z BUILD_BUILDNUMBER: 0.1.0.12
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6346370Z Version: 0.1.0.12
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6346370Z Checking pattern is specified
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6502638Z No Pattern found in solution parameter.
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6502638Z Found files: 1
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6502638Z --File: "E:\WebWork\10\s\Dev\DDS\DDSCommon\DDSCommon.csproj"
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6502638Z Creating Nuget Arguments:
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6658895Z --ARGS: pack "E:\WebWork\10\s\Dev\DDS\DDSCommon\DDSCommon.csproj" -OutputDirectory "\\Server\Nuget\DDS\" -Properties Configuration=Release -version 0.1.0.12
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6658895Z Invoking nuget with pack "E:\WebWork\10\s\Dev\DDS\DDSCommon\DDSCommon.csproj" -OutputDirectory "\\Server\Nuget\DDS\" -Properties Configuration=Release -version 0.1.0.12 on E:\WebWork\10\s\Dev\DDS\DDSCommon
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6658895Z \\Server\nuget\ pack "E:\WebWork\10\s\Dev\DDS\DDSCommon\DDSCommon.csproj" -OutputDirectory "\\Server\Nuget\DDS\" -Properties Configuration=Release -version 0.1.0.12
2017-04-12T20:46:59.6815141Z ##[error]Access is denied
```

we are using Internal NuGet Repo which is just a shared directory on our server.
On research could not find any posts related to it. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update from OP**

Issue fixed by leave blank of  `Path to Nuget.exe` field.

> *Path to NuGet.exe*
>
> (Optional) Path to your own instance of NuGet.exe. If you specify
>   this argument, you must have your own [strategy to handle
>   authentication.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/nuget-exe)

---

According to the error info  `Access is denied`. Please make sure your build service account have **enough permission** to access  `\\Server\Nuget\DDS\`

> **Package Folder**
>
> (Optional) Specify the folder where you want to put the packages. You
>   can use a variable such as `$(Build.StagingDirectory)\packages`
>
> If you leave it empty, the package will be created in the same
>   directory that contains the `.csproj` or `.nuspec` file.

You could also give a try with some other variable or leave it empty of the *package folder* in the nuget package task. To narrow down if the issue is related to shared directory `\\Server\Nuget\DDS\` on your server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Patrick. Tried to specifically add build service account with Read&Execute permission to the shared directory and even left the package folder empty in the task but again ended up with the same error. Do you think it can be something related to this -[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606007/tfs-2015-1-vnext-using-nuget-packager-but-cant-create-package-invalid-argu].

Comment: Got it Working. Error was i specified shared path to "Path to Nuget.exe" field, which is optional to fill. All i had to do was to leave it blank and it worked. @Patrick you were close.